# Where to get Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Where do you get Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll? I see it included in a lot of ASP.NET MVC open-source projects but it's not on my system after having installed ASP.NET MVC Beta and .NET 3.5 SP1.

In the ASP.NET MVC Beta source code from codeplex.com the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll is produced by the MvcFutures project. Is everyone compiling this module themselves?

**EDIT:** now that I know what it's called I see where Scott Gu mentions it in his release notes: [ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx#ten)

Comment: please see my post below for the final 1.0 version

Comment: K folks, we're already on version 3.  Stop flagging this and its answers like it was asked yesterday.

Comment: Voting to re-open - I don't think this question should be closed.  MVC Futures is an ongoing "project," and people are going to wonder what Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll is regardless of the version.  Even if the question gets out-of-date, it still is useful to know where the dll comes from.

Comment: Voting to reopen, I'm just having this exact problem myself.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's the MVC Futures project.

MVC 1.0 Futures:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471

MVC 2 Futures:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742

MVC 3 Futures:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Comment: Is this also needed for, or compatible with, MVC 2, I wonder?

Comment: P.S., this page comes up first in Google for "Microsoft.Web.Mvc", hence my commenting here in a one-and-a-half year old answer...

Comment: I just added the link for MVC 2 Futures.

Comment: Is there a link for MVC 3 Futures binaries?

Comment: MVC dll is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is the final 1.0 version !

[ASP.NET MVC v1.0 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471)

application, 104K, uploaded Mar 12

Answer (score 1):

The above page has been moved to http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471. From there download the Data Annotations Model Binder Sample. Then compile it and build it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might still be looking for this many years later (to revive an old bit of source code, for example, as I was), there are now Nuget packages for the various versions of MVC Futures (which gives you access to the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace).

They are imaginatively named, after the version of MVC they belong with:

- Mvc2Futures
- Mvc3Futures
- Mvc4Futures

...apart from the MVC 5 one, which is called

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it was already built and included.

Comment: I believe it was once included with ASP.NET 3.5 Extensions Preview 2 which is no longer available. You apparently have to get it separate from the ASP.NET MVC Beta install now.

Comment: It was there in MVC Preview 4.

Comment: We removed it as of the Beta release, because it's not part of the final RTM. It's a collection of potential future features as well as a bit of a playground for experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET MVC RC1 the new address is
http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22359

Answer (score 0):

Tak a look at this blog. It highlights areas of the MVC Future

http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the Data Annotations Model Binder Sample at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471 . Then compile and build the project.