# How can I render a different controller's action from within a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that within a view I can render an action from the same controller using Html.RenderPartial. However, I need to render the output from an action under a different controller. What is the best way to do this? I would prefer to do this directly within the view, rather than doing it in the controller and saving the output to a ViewData variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is use `Html.RenderAction` which needs a references to the 'Futures' assembly `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` which [there's a question about how to get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334408/where-to-get-microsoftwebmvcdll).

You will also need to add the namespace in your web.config in order to user it in your view:

```
<add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try shortly when I get to work. For some reason that method does not show in the typeaahead, though. When I Type "Html.", the only render method that shows in the list is RenderPartial. Do you get the same behavior? This is using the Express edition of Visual Web Dev.

Comment: I think you need another reference, see the changes I made to my answer

Comment: I have downloaded the Futures assembly and added a reference to it, and still the Html.RenderAction method is not found or usable. I am using the latest MVC release (10/13/2008) and Futures (10/16/2008).

Comment: you need to add the namespace in your web.config in order to user it in your view:

        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>

Comment: I'd added the need for a reference in your web.config to my answer

Comment: Note that I also needed to do a rebuild before the namespace was found, simply adding the reference and namespace in web.config was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Steve Sanderson's implementation of "Partial Requests" found [here](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/)