# ASP.NET MVC Generic Html and Url helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Where has the generic html controls and url helpers gone ?

You know the ones that looked something like this:

```
this.TextBox<MyInputModel>(model=>model.Name)

this.ActionLink<MyController>(controller=>controller.Index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are extensions located in the assembly Micosoft.Web.MVC.
You have to add this assembly to your project and add a reference to it in the web.config file.
You should consult the following answer for more details: [Where to get Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334408/where-to-get-microsoftwebmvcdll)

Answer (score 1):

These are (and have always been, I think) in the MvcFutures assembly.  You need to update to the newest MvcFutures when you upgrade to the released version.

Answer (score 0):

They should appear on a generic view. i.e.

```
ViewPage<MyInputModel>
```

or generic user control

```
ViewUserControl<MyInputModel>
```

but that should read

```
html.TextBox(model=>model.Name)
```

Beware that is untested code.