# ASP.NET MVC2 missing Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've seen quite a few references to the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Controls namespace in MVC examples, but I don't have that assembly or namespace available. I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 Preview 2.

Anyone know where I should be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this question:

[Where to get Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334408/where-to-get-microsoft-web-mvc-dll)

Get them here:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471

Comment: Thanks; brain cramped and didn't see the difference between "system.web.mvc" and "microsoft.web.mvc."