# Where to find Microsoft.Web.Mvc dll for MVC 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to add a reference to this dll so I need to download it in my bin folder, the thing is that not being very fluent in English I can't manage to find it, I only find later versions (or at least it's what I understand)

Does any one knows where to find older versions?

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334408/where-to-get-microsoft-web-mvc-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download and install it from the links below and I am sure that it has the dll you are looking for.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471 (as discussed on the link which sikander added)
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5388

Comment: You're completely right. I have arrived to that question googling but I thought it wasn't the dll but another thing due to its name. Thanks a lot!!!!